# I am making a children s educational game, what would be the best option?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which will help children with their education. The application will include simple drag and drop activities. I have searched the internet for engines and found some quite good ones but was wondering if just using Android itself would be adequate for these simple activities that are not really demanding?

What do you think?

Comment: I think Android is likely enough, but (a) the question has almost nothing with which we could help determine a real answer, and (b) it's unlikely there's a definitive answer anyway.

Comment: Cheers Dave, well I am just wondering if the Android library would be able to handle simple drag and drop applications smoothly. Like dragging coins, answering sums and playing sounds. It may be simple and an engine may make it more complicated than need be.

Comment: Yes, that's all quite easy to do, with just a custom view to draw everything and bitmaps for your coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple drag and drop activities won't be a problem in android, iOS or Windows phone.
I would be more concerned about which platforms are more likely to be used by kids, to be honest.
In South Africa, for instance, most kids have blackberries which don't even have touch screens because data is too expensive.

check this out:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

and

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/android-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html

also check out the android developer documentation